Laravel Delete record from Ajax Call - Button click event not working
I am trying to delete a record from ajax call in a laravel crud. But the click event seems not working. Therefore delete function is not working. Here is my code.
web.php
Route::delete('/categories/destroy/{id}', [CategoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('categories.destroy');

CategoryController.php
public function index(Request $request){
        $categories = CategoryModel::select('id', 'name', 'type');

        if ($request->ajax()){
            return DataTables::of($categories)
                ->addColumn('action', function ($row){
                   return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info editButton" data-id="'.$row->id.'">Edit</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" id="delButton" data-id="'.$row->id.'">Delete</a>';
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
    }

public function destroy($id){
        $category = CategoryModel::find($id);
        if (! $category){
            abort(404);
        }
        $category->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'success'=>'Category Deleted Successfully'
        ], 201);
    }

create.blade.php
<body>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="modal-title"></h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <form action="" id="cretateCategoryForm">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" id="category_id">
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
                        <span id="nameError" class="text-danger error-messages"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="" class="">Category Name</label>
                        <select id="type" name="type" class="form-control mb-1">
                            <option disabled selected>Choose Option</option>
                            <option value="electronic">Electronics</option>
                        </select>
                        <span id="typeError" class="text-danger error-messages"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"id="saveBtn"></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-3" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-info mb-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="add_category">Add Category</a>

        <table class="table" id="category-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.3/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var table = $('#category-table').DataTable({
            processData: true,
            serverSide: true,

            ajax: "{{ route('categories.index') }}",
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'name' },
                { data: 'type' },
                { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable:false },
            ]
        })

       $('#modal-title').html('Create Category');
       $('#saveBtn').html('Save Category');

       var form = $('#cretateCategoryForm')[0];
       $('#saveBtn').click(function () {

            $('.error-messages').html('');
            var formData = new FormData(form);

            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route("categories.store") }}',
                method: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: formData,

                success: function (response) {
                    table.draw();
                    $('#name').val('');
                    $('#type').val('');
                    $('#category_id').val('');
                    if(response){
                        $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                        swal("Success!", response.success, "success");
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    if(error){
                        console.log(error.responseJSON.errors.name);
                        $('#nameError').html(error.responseJSON.errors.name);
                        $('#typeError').html(error.responseJSON.errors.type);
                    }
                }
            });
       });

            $('body').on('click', '#delButton', function (){
                var id  = $(this).data('id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url("/categories/destroy", '') }}' + '/' + id,
                    method: 'DELETE',

                    success: function (response){
                        table.draw();
                        swal("Success!", response.success, "success");
                    },
                    error: function (error){
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                });
            });
            
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

I tried everthing I could. None of stackoverflow previous solutions for same problems like this one are not working as well. Please help me. Thank You!

Your delete button is delButtonCae, not delButton

Hi. Sorry. It's typo. I corrected it. Issue remain same

Is this a jQuery problem, a JSON problem, or a Laravel problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

"But the click event seems not working" - how did you check that? Do you see the request in your browser's developer console? Does it contain the proper data?

It's looks like issue with how the URL for the AJAX request is being constructed in my JS code. There is no request logged under console in button click. First I debugged by add console logs inside  success function, No message or error messages logged in browser console. I modified url inside ajax call as url: '{{ url("categories/destroy") }}/' + id , added header inside ajax call - headers: {             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' =         }, and many more. Nothing worked.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If no request is logged after all, this problem might be unrelated to PHP or Laravel

The value of the id attribute must be unique to access and manipulate the element with the specific id. So, you can trigger the click event by using class name -
$('body').on('click', '.btn-danger', function (){
    ....
})

